# A dependency cycle was detected when trying to resolve the AuthenticationManager (Spring Security and Oauth)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm getting following error when configuring spring security, can anyone help me? The current configuration have resource server and authentication servers in same server for testing, may this causing conflicts.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: A dependency cycle was detected when trying to resolve the AuthenticationManager. Please ensure you have configured authentication.
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.validateBeanCycle(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:462)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.<init>(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:430)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManagerBean(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:220)
    at org.blanc.whiteboard.security.configuration.SecurityConfig$ApiWebSecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:283)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:68)
    at org.blanc.whiteboard.security.configuration.SecurityConfig$ApiWebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2cbb9c9d.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:367)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6effe0e.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$4(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6effe0e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3d548252.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6effe0e.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 30 more
```

### Web security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler(){
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Autowired
        private Validator validator;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
            return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Autowired
        private OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Bean
        public OAuthRestEntryPoint oauthRestEntryPoint()
        {
            return new OAuthRestEntryPoint();
        }

//      @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
//      @Override
//      public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
//              throws Exception {
//          return super.authenticationManagerBean();
//      }

        @Bean
        public ClientDetailsUserDetailsService clientDetailsUserDetailsService(){
            return new ClientDetailsUserDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        }
        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, validator, passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Bean
        protected AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
            OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
            entryPoint.setTypeName("Basic");
            entryPoint.setRealmName("test");
            return entryPoint;
        }



        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.anonymous().disable()
            .antMatcher("/oauth/token")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(oauthRestEntryPoint())
            .and()
                .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/token")).disable()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler)
            .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter filter = new ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter();
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            filter.afterPropertiesSet();
            http.addFilterBefore(filter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http.addFilterAfter(filter, SpringCrossOriginResourceSharingFilter.class);
        }


    }
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    protected static class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Bean(name = "clientAuthenticationManager")
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
                throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }


        @Autowired
        private OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;
        @Bean
        public OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint clientAuthenticationEntryPoint(){
            OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint clientAuthenticationEntrypoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
            clientAuthenticationEntrypoint.setTypeName("Basic");
            return clientAuthenticationEntrypoint;
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.anonymous().disable().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(clientAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/v1.0/users")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1.0/users").permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        }




    }


}
```

### Oauthserver config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableResourceServer
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
@ImportResource({
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/oauth/client-details.xml"
})
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
//      @Autowired
//      private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


        @Autowired
        private ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter(){
            ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter clientFilter = new ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter();
//          clientFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            return clientFilter;
        }

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        public OAuth2AccessTokenRepository oAuth2AccessTokenRepository;

        @Autowired
        public OAuth2RefreshTokenRepository oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository;

        @Bean
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(){
            final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            defaultTokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(true);
            defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            defaultTokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
            return defaultTokenServices;
        }

        @Bean
        public OAuth2RepositoryTokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new OAuth2RepositoryTokenStore(oAuth2AccessTokenRepository,
                    oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
                throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess(
                    "isAnonymous || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')")
                    .realm("test");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
                throws Exception {
            clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints
//          .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .clientDetailsService(clientDetailsService).tokenServices(tokenServices())
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `ResourceServerConfig`, you've overridden `authenticationManagerBean()` but never configured the authenticationManager as [instructed in the api reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManagerBean()), specifically

> Override this method to expose the AuthenticationManager from
>   configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) to be exposed as a Bean.

For example ...

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.authenticationProvider(new MyCustomAuthProvider());
}
```

See the [configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder)) for details.

Comment: and what is MyCustomAuthProvider? I don't have one